# Raspberry pi 3 Model B no autoconnect wifi when I shutdown

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi3, Model B connecting to Wi-Fi.
I have the Raspberry 3 display 7" where I can see if Wi-Fi is connected.

When I connect and disconnect the Raspberry with ethernet wire the Wi-Fi works, then when I reboot the Wi-Fi works perfectly too, and **I can reboot whenever I want and Wi-Fi works**.

But when the Raspberry Pi **shuts down and wakes up Wi-Fi doesn't work**.

The file /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf:

```
 network={
    ssid="My_wifi_name"
    psk="Password"
}
```

Some idea?
If you need another file say me please, I'm new here.

Comment: You should ask this on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com .

Comment: ok thanks I do it too. I'm little noob here.

Comment: That's okay! I think you'll find better help over there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the Raspberry Pi StackExchange.